# How to decode float32 encoded png to tensor?

Tags: tensorflow

How can I decode a png image that has encoded float32 values in the argb pixel channels to a float32 tensor? For example as the depth images provided by the [KITTI](http://www.cvlibs.net/datasets/kitti/eval_depth.php?benchmark=depth_prediction) dataset.

The function

```
tf.image.decode_png()
```

can only give me uint8 or uint16 values and not the correct float32 values.

Is there any workaround or solution to get such a float32 tensorflow tensor?

**Edit:**
So in the png each channel stores a uint8 value. And all 4 channels (argb) together make up a float32 value. This can actually easily be read with PIL and numpy (this code was provided by the KITTI dataset):

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

depth_png = np.array(Image.open(filename), dtype=int)
depth = depth_png.astype(np.float) / 256.
```

Here the int is at least a int32 I guess so that the information is preserved.

However, I am looking for a way to somehow get this to a tensorflow Tensor that I can load on the fly in the dataset.

Comment: Are you looking for `.png` to `tfrecords` conversion?

Comment: I am looking for a way to get the 4 uint8 values that are stored in every channel of the png to decode them to a single float32 tensor.

Answer (score 2):

The .png format stores the channel values as uint8.

To convert to float32 between 0 and 1 we can just cast then divide by 255 (the max value of uint8).

Something like this:

```py
img_bytes = tf.io.read_file('path/img.png')
img_tensor_uint8 = tf.image.decode_png(img_bytes)
img_tensor_float32 = tf.cast(img_tensor_uint8, tf.float32) / 255
```

Comment: I am not sure if this works correctly. When I do this I get strange values. The png stores uint8 for every channel (argb) as a way to represent a single float32 value so all channels together form the 32 bit float. When I decode to a uint8 tensor first I think this information gets lost. I think I need 4 uint8 tensors to represent the same information as a float32 tensor.

Comment: The PNG file does indeed store a uint8 for every channel. All 4 of these channels are returned from `decode_png` - the shape of the tensor returned is (height X width X channels). One would ordinarily keep these 4 channels for downstream training but convert the uints to floats and normalise. There is no loss of info: we can undo the conversion precisely by multiplying by 255 then  converting back to int

Comment: Hm so when I decode with channels=0 I get just one channel. When I decode with channels=4 I still have 4 float32 maps after the cast. So this does not seem to do this conversion correctly. Maybe the png does somehow also store this information differently. I edited my question with the provided KITTI numpy/PIL code to read these png images. They also divide by 256. Do you maybe have an idea how this actually works and transfer it to tensorflow?

Comment: Okay the problem was that the png are actually greyscale uint16 values and not 4 channel uin8 values. So it was my mistake. I will answer my question myself but give you an upvote because your answer is also correct for general use cases.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem here was that the KITTI png images are greyscale uint16 values. With this the correct decoding is:

```
image = tf.read_file(path)
image = tf.image.decode_png(image, channels=0, dtype=tf.uint16)
image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
image = image / 256.0
```

Stewart_R answer is of course also correct for general use cases.

Comment: It is 255, not 256